# php create arrays dynamically and merge

Tags: php, arrays, loops, array-merge

I'm trying to create an unknown number of arrays dynamically inside a *foreach* loop, merge them all at the end into one array, and use this in a JSON format for Google Analytics.

So far I have the following code which is throwing an error at the merge part:

```
        $p=1;
        foreach(...){
        ...
        $arr = 'arr'.$p;
        $name = $order->ProductGroupName;
        $name = str_replace("'", "", $name);
        $arr = array(
            "name"=>$name,
            "id"=>$order->ProductCode,
            "price"=>$order->RRP,
            "quantity"=>$order->Quantity
        );
            $p++;       
        }
        for ($q = 1; $q<$p; $q++){
            $arry = 'arr'.$q;
            $merge = array_merge($arry, $merge);
        };
```

How do I create the arrays dynamically and merge them at the end, please? 
I'm relatively new to PHP and have tried my best to get this to work.

Comment: `foreach(...){
        ...`??? What???  Also, there is no `$arry` maybe `$arr`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver theres a lot of other code I didn't want to copy and paste so substituted it with the dots.  $arry is defined in the for loop at the bottom

Comment: Please note that providing a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) usually helps to get useful anwers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  Just dynamically append `[]` to the array and you don't need to merge:

```
foreach($something as $order) {
    $arr[] = array (
        "name"=>str_replace("'", "", $order->ProductGroupName),
        "id"=>$order->ProductCode,
        "price"=>$order->RRP,
        "quantity"=>$order->Quantity
    );
}
```

If you want to have string keys for whatever reason, then:

```
$p = 1;
foreach($something as $order) {
    $arr["SomeText$p"] = array (
        "name"=>str_replace("'", "", $order->ProductGroupName),
        "id"=>$order->ProductCode,
        "price"=>$order->RRP,
        "quantity"=>$order->Quantity
    );
    $p++;
}
```

And that's it.  Check with:

```
print_r($arr);
```

Things like `$arry = 'arr'.$q;` stink of variable variables (though not done correctly) and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thank you - thats exactly what I'm trying to achieve